# How to add custom messages to jQuery validation plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to create a custom message for the method "mustBeFigaro". At the moment I am getting the default messages for email, but not my custom message for the promo code.

So far I have been able to change existing messages in the plugin code, but not add new messages.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.validator.addMethod("mustBeFigaro", function(value, element) {
return (value.toLowerCase && (value.toLowerCase() === "figaro"));
},
"Please enter valid promo code."
);
$("#emailSubscription").validate({
ignore: ".ignore",
    rules: {
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
    'entry.369082719': {
      required: true,
      mustBeFigaro:true
    }
        },
    submitHandler: function(form){
        $('#emailSubscription').toggle();
        form.submit();
        $('.hidden-message').show(500);
    }
})
});
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/medgoQ?editors=101

Comment: I have no idea what's wrong with your Codepen, but the same exact code is working perfectly fine in a jsFIddle.  All error messages are working:  http://jsfiddle.net/hq9gzLbo/ ~  Apparently, there is something within your own CSS that is hiding the error message element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the JavaScript code you posted and the jQuery Validate plugin is working fine.  The problem is that your custom CSS is hiding the error message underneath the second `input` element.  So I removed all `position` properties from your CSS which then allows the elements to move out of the way when the error messages are inserted.

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/okehhjr6/**

Comment: Thanks, that was driving me mad.

Answer (score 0):

Change your custom function,

```
return (value.toLowerCase && (value.toLowerCase() === "figaro"));
```

To,

```
return (value.toLowerCase && (value.toLowerCase() === "figaro") &&  value != "" );
```